# Function doesn't use variables defined above it

Tags: php

I have a variable named $url in the top of my file:

```
<?php
$url = "http://myurl.com";
```

Later in the same file, I have this code:

```
<?php
$url = "http://myurl.com";
[...]
function errorOut($error, $type = "info", $rel = "/")
{
    echo $url;
}
?>
```

However, that doesn't work, because it says `$url` isn't a valid variable. I have to do this:

```
<?php
$url = "http://myurl.com";
[...]
function errorOut($error, $type = "info", $rel = "/")
{
    $url = "http://myurl.com";
    echo $url;
}
?>
```

This doesn't make any sense to me because it shouldn't be out of scope because it's a layer above the function. How do I make it use the earlier `$url` variable?

Comment: Read about [variable scope](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php), and pass `$url` to the function as an argument

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php

Answer (score 1):

by passing the `$url` in your function:

```
function errorOut($error, $type = "info", $rel = "/", $url) //<<< here
```

and also calling it:

```
errorOut('...','...','...',$url);
```

**NON WORKING EXAMPLE AS SEEN IN YOUR ANSWER**

```
$a = 'test1';
$b = 'test2';
define ('URL','one');
define ('URL', 'two');
test($a,$b);

function test ($a,$b){
    echo $a;
    echo $b;
    echo URL;
}
```

Won't work, URL will stay at 'one' // Will only work if you never want to change URL

Comment: I can't do `function errorOut($error, $type = "info", $rel = "/", $url = $url)` and I don't want to change the way I call it every time because I call it all the time. Is there something else you suggest?

Comment: Well, no. You can use the other answer from @Omnikrys, but using globals is evil... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5166087/php-global-in-functions/5166527#5166527

Answer (score 1):

They are not in the same scope. You have to let PHP know you will be using that global locally. It is preferable to not use a global and instead pass it as a variable though.

```
<?php
$url = "http://myurl.com";
[...]
function errorOut($error, $type = "info", $rel = "/")
{
    global $url;
    echo $url;
}
?>
```

See [Variable scope](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php) for more information.

Comment: Incoming downvotes in 3...2...1. Please check out [dependency injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection).

Comment: Why downvote? His answer is correct, and even states that it is not the best way to do this....

Comment: The question was why doesn't it work. I explained that. Not sure where the problem is here.

Comment: @Omnikrys Because as `errorOut` expands into a larger function, and other functions that use `$url` modify it, then you'll start to have difficult code to debug because you won't know which function changed `$url`. When you start to have more variables that are globalized, the problem will only magnify.

Comment: I'm well aware of the problem of globals and best practices but the question wasn't "should I use a global?" it was "why doesn't this work?". Throwing principles and patterns at someone who doesn't understand variable scope in PHP when that wasn't even their question makes no sense to me.

Answer (score 1):

I was talking to someone in an IRC about this (he posted on here too before I joined), he said I should use

```
define("URL", 'http://example.com');
```

And whenever I reference that variable I should use URL, *not* $url

Comment: If you are using this, you will not be able to change URL, I've edited my answer with an example